# Cygwin inside Windows container, coreutils do not work in volumes

Tags: cygwin, docker, docker-for-windows, coreutils

I set up Cygwin inside a Windows Docker container and some common operations just fail when executed in Docker volumes.

Examples:

```
$ mkdir foo bar
$ mv foo bar
mv: cannot move 'bar' to a subdirectory of itself, 'foo/bar'
$ ls foo
$ ls bar
$ rmdir foo bar
rmdir: failed to remove 'foo': Invalid argument
rmdir: failed to remove 'bar': Invalid argument
```

These commands work fine in the main filesystem but return errors in the attached volumes (created with `docker volume create` and mounted with `-v volume:mountpoint`).
If I switch to a PowerShell prompt, I am able to move and delete the folders without issues.

If I try to run `strace mv foo bar` I obtain the following

```
  [...]
  260  126481 [main] mv 1661 path_conv::check: this->path(C:\ext-libs\bar\foo), has_acls(1)
  463  126944 [main] mv 1661 seterrno_from_nt_status: /home/corinna/src/cygwin/cygwin-3.2.0/cygwin-3.2.0-1.x86_64/src/newlib-cygwin/winsup/cygwin/syscalls.cc:2834 status 0xC000000D -> windows error 87
  313  127257 [main] mv 1661 geterrno_from_win_error: windows error 87 == errno 22
  216  127473 [main] mv 1661 rename2: -1 = rename(foo, bar/foo), errno 22
  [...]
```

I am using the image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1909` on Windows 1909, with Docker version 20.10.6 build 370c289.

To install Cygwin I use a simple BAT script that runs the official installer and pre-installs some useful packages.

I am not sure if I am expecting too much from Cygwin or there is something else I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue with Git bash inside a windows docker container.

A workaround is to copy the file outside the docker volume then move it back inside and rename it:

```
cp foo /c/
mv /c/foo bar
```